# android chrome shadow content height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am encountering an issue in the Android Chrome browser on a mobile phone.

The input type 'text' has a height of 52px, a font size of 15px, and a line height of 21px. However, the shadow content height remains at 17.7px. Shouldn't it be 21px to match the line height?

I need to ensure that the content height doesn't vary when a user pastes an emoji. Currently, the input content jerks when a user pastes an emoji into the input field. The reason for this jerking is that the shadow DOM height increases by 1px. If I simply set the shadow height to 21px, this jerking will stop. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

2 potential ways to fix it

by using `overflow-y: hidden;`

```
input {
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 21px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

another by using `line-height: normal;`

```
input {
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

remember to change selector to target only the specific input element

As potential as it is, but it should still prevent the jerking when pasting emojis.

Comment: not working both. I am testing on android chrome browser in emulator.

Comment: sure nothing is interfering  ?

Comment: yes I am certain. It is just happening in android chrome.

Comment: strange, can you comment off, all selectors targeting it and test it? or use important

Comment: is there any way to set emoji pasted height?

Comment: overflow-y is not working since I am using padding 23px top, 8px bottom. content is still jerking after setting overyflow-y: hidden due to this.

Comment: it is hard to say anything like this, i think there is something off with it

you can try use a font which dodnt let emoji change size or try with fixed height

Answer (score 0):

using box-sizing: content-box on an input and then setting line height solved the bug. Also had to remove input height as well.